# In mysql how do I find rows whose id are not referenced in any other rows in the table?

Tags: mysql

My table has three columns

```
ID   parent_ID   item
```

As you can understand, it's for a nested menu. Now I need to find those elements which don't have any child elements. In other words, whose id isn't being used as parent_ID for any other rows( and order them by `item`). Can I do this with a mysql query?

Comment: Would be helpful to show us your table structures

Comment: He kind of did - it's a simple table of those three columns.  It sounds like he wants to do a kind of `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT parent_ID FROM table)`  Edit: I'd post this as a potential answer but I can't test it since I don't have a database handy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a LEFT JOIN instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT Parents.* FROM mytable Parents
LEFT JOIN mytable Childs ON Parents.ID = Childs.parent_ID
WHERE Childs.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable m WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable m2 WHERE m2.parent_ID = m.ID)
```